# How do I set the IP Address of a device using Windows Universal App?

Tags: raspberry-pi, win-universal-app, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 ioT installed.  How do I set the IP Address statically in code?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by [connecting remotely to your device via Powershell](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm) and running "netsh".

You can perform a variety of tasks using the Netsh command-line utility, including configuring the IP addresses of network adapters in Windows.

**Here’s how to configure a static IP address:**

netsh interface ip set address "connection name" static 192.168.0.101 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1

NOTE: The default connection names are Local Area Connection for wired adapters and Wireless Network Connection for Wi-Fi adapters. The IP address order: client IP, subnet mask, and gateway IP.

**Here’s how to configure the DNS addresses:**

netsh interface ip add dns "connection name" 208.67.222.222

netsh interface ip add dns "connection name" 208.67.220.220 index=2

**NOTE:** Remember to replace the connection names and IP addresses.

Comment: Yep.  I get that.  I'm wondering if it can be done via the Windows UAP 10 ioT application running on the device.

Comment: I have not tried the Power-Shell method yet, but I am wondering if it will persist after a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Now it can be done directly with Windows Device Portal (with your browser)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it cannot be done via code at this time.

Answer (score 0):

First start the session with iOT via Windows PowerShell [Using PowerShell to connect and configure a device running Windows 10 IoT Core](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm)

Then follow [How to Change Your IP Address Using PowerShell](http://www.howtogeek.com/112660/how-to-change-your-ip-address-using-powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess It's a bit late, but after several research, the only solution I have found out that works so far (C#) is using ShellStream class from SSH.NET (Renci):

```
 SshClient client = new SshClient(host, username, password);
 client.Connect();

 ShellStream stream = client.CreateShellStream("shellName", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);
```

Then you can manipulate the stream through StreamReader/StreamWriter and call writeLine() to introduce the cmds into the Shell.

PS: You need to install SSH.NET using the Nuget Manager, by typing the next line on the console: Install-Package SSH.NET -Pre

Hope It helps.