# Discover raspberry's IP

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi3, iot, windows-10-iot-core, access-point

I have a Raspberry with win 10 IoT, working as a main server for a cloud of sensors. In the raspberry I have a server that broadcast its IP using UDP broadcast. Then all my distributed sensors notice it and  connect to the Raspberry via TCP and the fun can start.

I added a web server to the raspberry to be able to monitor the status of my sensors and then I encountered a funny problem .. how do I discover the IP of the raspberry to be able to enter the website ??

All my sensors (and the PI) have hardcoded the SSID and pass of my WiFi at home. But the thing will need to be portable. In theory I plan to set the pi as Access Point and hardcode in the sensors the SSID of the Pi and have a portable system.

Can a Pi on Windows IoT be set as AP ? When doing so can it's IP be forced ?

Comment: if people downvoting don't explain why we will never get to know how to improve.. just saying ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a Pi on Windows IoT be set as AP ?

Windows IoT Core device can be set as soft AP. When the Windows 10 IoT Device have access to the internet (e.g. through a wired LAN connection), it can share the Internet access with other devices connected to your device over the Wi-Fi SoftAP via [Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/deviceportal#iot-onboarding). You can follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/deviceportal#iot-onboarding) to do this.

> When doing so can it's IP be forced ?

You can set a static IP address to the device. For example, via the device portal, like this:

[image]

More information of setting static IP of the Raspberry Pi running Windows IoT Core you can reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837511/how-do-i-set-the-ip-address-of-a-device-using-windows-universal-app).

Comment: this is the perfect set up for me. Specially being able to share internet.. I expected my sensors to be "hard to debug" once connected to the AP bt .. everything went better than expected!